# Prime React Calender Positioning Issue

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Using primereact calendar for both date & Time selection.
code

```
<Calendar name="enddate"
          id="enddate"
          placeholder="End Time "
          style={{ width: "100%"}}
          inputStyle={{ width: "90%" }}
          showButtonBar={true}
          hideOnDateTimeSelect={true}
          showTime={true}
          showSeconds={true}
          hourFormat="24"
          showIcon={true}
          monthNavigator={true}
          value={this.props.enddate}
          ></Calendar>
```

output image attached

the problem is that the overlay is covering the input field.
I tried a lot, but didn't find any props for showing calendar below the input field.
I also tried custom styling but was not successful.

Any Suggestions or updates?

[image]

Comment: can you please share codesandbox link ?

Comment: this is a problem when the calendar popup doesnt have the space required to fully show on top or below the textbox. What i would suggest is to change the css in order to narrow the calendar popup height as a first step and see if this fits your needs.